# socat: call from script, bashrc or systemd?

Tags: shell-script, systemd, serial-port, socat

I want to use socat to direct serial commands over ethernet
to an ethernet-serial converter (static IP address). 
I am wondering what would be a good way of starting socat.

As I understand it, systemd would allow me
to ensure socat is always running – or in case of failure, tries to restart. 
The .service file would look like:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Unit] 
Description=my socat test
User=me
Group=me

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '~/my_socat.sh'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
socat PTY,link=/home/me/dev/valve1 TCP:192.168.11.101:5001 & socat PTY,link=/home/me/dev/valve2 TCP:192.168.11.101:5002
```

Would this approach do what I want? 
Would socat be restarted if it dies for some reason? 
And what would happen if the ethernet connection
is not available when socat is started? 
Running it from the shell without network connection does not work,
and the command fails with the error message "network is unreachable".

How should I make sure socat is running
before my (Python) script is executed? 
Should I start socat from within Python?

Answer (score 0):

To see how to setup socat via scripts, please see this post and this gist:

[Intercept communications on physical serial port using socat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/711700/intercept-communications-on-physical-serial-port-using-socat/759582#759582)

https://gist.github.com/krzyklo/e60793b27400be7a330042aa6bdf388a

`socat -x -d -d pty,raw,echo=0,link=/tmp/cryocon_simulator pty,raw,echo=0,link=/tmp/cryocon`

Below scripts from links, to have all in one place:
`my-serial.py`

```
import sys
import serial
DEFAULT_ADDR = '/home/krzys/myserial'
DEFAULT_CMD = 'R5'
args = len(sys.argv) - 1
if args == 0:
    addr, cmd = DEFAULT_ADDR, DEFAULT_CMD
elif args == 1:
    addr, cmd = DEFAULT_ADDR, sys.argv[1]
else:
    addr, cmd = sys.argv[1:3]

cmd += '\r\n'
s = serial.Serial("/home/krzys/myserial",9600,timeout=0.5)
s.write(cmd.encode())
print(s.readline())
```

client.py

```
import sys
import serial
DEFAULT_ADDR = '/tmp/cryocon'
DEFAULT_CMD = '*IDN?'
args = len(sys.argv) - 1
if args == 0:
    addr, cmd = DEFAULT_ADDR, DEFAULT_CMD
elif args == 1:
    addr, cmd = DEFAULT_ADDR, sys.argv[1]
else:
    addr, cmd = sys.argv[1:3]

cmd += '\n'
s = serial.serial_for_url(addr)
s.write(cmd.encode())
print(s.readline())
```

simulator.py

```
import sys
import logging

import serial

DEFAULT_ADDR = '/tmp/cryocon_simulator'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

addr = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else DEFAULT_ADDR

conn = serial.serial_for_url(addr)
logging.info(f'Ready to receive requests on {addr}')
while True:
    request = conn.readline()
    logging.info('REQ: %r', request)
    request = request.strip().decode().lower()
    reply = 'Cryo-con,24C,305682,1.05A\n' if request == '*idn?' else 'NACK\n'
    reply = reply.encode()
    logging.info('REP: %r', reply)
    conn.write(reply)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/464341)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).